# SQL- Only keep square brackets and data inside those

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was looking for a way to dynamically parse a string:

**Input:** `A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]`

**Output:** `[1][2][1]`

Comment: You should know by now that you should show us your efforts...

Comment: I have already tried doing it through patindex, but that's not dynamic.. because digits inside square brackets may vary every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using `while` loop.

```
declare @str varchar(max), @newStr varchar(max), @orgStr varchar(max)
set @orgStr = 'A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]'
set @newStr = ''
set @Str = @orgStr
while (1=1)
begin
    if (CHARINDEX('[',@str) <> 0)
        begin
            set @newStr = @newStr + SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('[',@str), CHARINDEX(']',@str) - CHARINDEX('[',@str)+1)
            set @str = STUFF(@str, CHARINDEX('[',@str), CHARINDEX(']',@str) - CHARINDEX('[',@str)+1, '')
        end
    else
        break
end
select @orgStr as input, @newStr as result
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx), if your compatibility level is 130 or greater. (Not the default for Azure, according to the docs. You may have to change the setting database-wide.)

If you split the string on '[', then you will have two sets of values: those containing a ']' and those not. If your string contains balanced left and right brackets, the first word should have no ']', since it contains everything before the first opening '['. Every other word should contain a closing ']'.

You can drop the first word, and then apply `STRING_SPLIT` again on the ']'. At this point, the let's-call-them-even rows will be indexes, and the call-them-odd rows will be text after the ']' and before the next '['.

Like this:

```
s = 'firstword[1][2] another word [foobar] biscuit'

SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(s, '[')
```

Should get you:

```
1: 'firstword'  #<-- No brackets here
2: '1]'
3: '2] another word '
4: 'foobar] biscuit'
```

You can drop the first row, of course. Applying `SPLIT_STRING` again will get you:

```
'1', ''
'2', ' another word'
'foobar', ' biscuit'
```

Keep the left column, discard the right column, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Thanks for thr help +1 for the help

Answer (score 2):

Use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX built in functions in CTE:

```
 DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]'
 ;WITH CTE_Split( SplitStr , String ) AS
 (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@String      
    ,CHARINDEX('[',@String),CHARINDEX('[',@String)+1),SUBSTRING(@String 
    ,CHARINDEX('/',@String)+1,LEN(@String))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('[',String) = 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(String  
    ,CHARINDEX('[',String),CHARINDEX('[',String)) END,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',String) = 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(String  
    ,CHARINDEX('/',String)+1,LEN(String)) END
    FROM CTE_Split
    WHERE String <> ''
  )

  SELECT SplitStr FROM CTE_Split 

  [OR]

  This query for all scenarios :

   DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]/C_D[288]/'

   ;WITH CTE_Split( SplitStr , String ) AS
   (
      SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX('/',@String)),SUBSTRING(@String  
      ,CHARINDEX('/',@String)+1,LEN(@String))
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',String) = 0 THEN '' ELSE   
      SUBSTRING(String ,0,CHARINDEX('/',String)) END,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',String) = 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(String  
      ,CHARINDEX('/',String)+1,LEN(String)) END
      FROM CTE_Split
      WHERE String <> ''
  )

  SELECT SUBSTRING(SplitStr,CHARINDEX('[',SplitStr),CHARINDEX(']',SplitStr))
  FROM CTE_Split
```

Comment: Fails with DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'A[1]/B2[223]/C_D[1]'. I suggest using ']' as the ending string delimeter instead of '/'

Comment: Fails badly with DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200) = 'A[1]/B2[223]/C_D[1]/E_F[2345]'

Comment: @Piyush Bhardwaj ,I updated my post.Check it now second query.

Answer (score 1):

```html
--===== Create and populate the Tally table on the fly
 SELECT TOP 11000 --equates to more than 30 years of dates
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
   INTO dbo.Tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--===== Add a Primary Key to maximize performance
  ALTER TABLE dbo.Tally
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100

--===== Allow the general public to use it
  GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Tally TO PUBLIC


  --===== Simulate a passed parameter
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(8000) 
    SET @Parameter = 'A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]' 

--===== Suppress the auto-display of rowcounts to keep them from being
    -- mistaken as part of the result set.
   SET NOCOUNT ON

--===== Get the items in the brackets and number them 
 SELECT  '[' + SUBSTRING(@Parameter,N+1,CHARINDEX(']',@Parameter,N+1)-N-1) + ']'
   FROM dbo.Tally
  WHERE N < LEN(@Parameter)
    AND SUBSTRING(@Parameter,N,1) = '['
```

Please try your Logic Like this

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly for me !!

Comment: thanks Piyush                        ...............................................................

Answer (score 1):

Can do it by a while loop with a combination of substring and charindex.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(max) = 'A[1]/B2[2]/C_D[1]';
declare @len as int = len(@str);
declare @i as int = 0;
declare @str2 as varchar(max) = @str;
declare @res as varchar(max) = '';

while(@len >= @i)
begin
    if (charindex('[',@str2) <> 0)
    begin
        set @res += substring(@str2, 
                              charindex('[', @str2, 1), 
                              charindex(']', @str2, 1) - charindex('[', @str2, 1) + 1)
        set @i += charindex(']', @str2, 1);
        set @str2 = right(@str2, @len - @i)
    end
    else
      break;    
end
select @res;
```